# How to move file from directory to another with spring integration and sftp

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am facing errors trying to move a file from one directory to another

here my code that i added

```
    
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "moveFiles" )
    public MessageHandler sftpPutHandler(){
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "mv", "headers['file_remoteFile']");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("headers['file_renameTo']"));
        sftpOutboundGateway.setChmod(777);
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }
    

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface fileGateway {
        
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "moveFiles")
        void rename(File file);
    }
```

actually i tried many times to change the new path of the file (the new placement) and i failed

Ihave got this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.getRemoteFilename(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:1238)

2023-01-29 00:18:56.923  WARN 15520 --- [ XNIO-2 task-17] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like you use very old Spring Integration version. See if you can upgrade to most recent: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#support.

Then I see that you configure your `SftpOutboundGateway` to rely on `file_remoteFile` and `file_renameTo` headers, but your `rename()` gateway contract does not populate those headers. Not sure what would you expect from the `SftpOutboundGateway` if you don't supply respective data...